# Modifying and assigning std::map, breaks the entire map in a specific cases

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have a class, that fills a map incorrectly. Below is an example of what happens.

```
typedef map<const Node*, vector<double> > Map; 

class Syst {
public:
    Syst(){}
    ~Syst(){}
    void mysyst(Map&,Map&);
};

void Syst::mysyst(Map& u,Map& res) {
    int sz = (*u.begin()).second.size();
    Map::iterator it = u.begin();
    for(; it != u.end(); ++it){
       vector<double> tmp(sz,0.0);
       const Node* node = (*it).first;
       res[node] = tmp;
       if(node->id() > 100) {
           res[node][0] = 1.0;
           cout << node->id() << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

First, I create 125 nodes, and assign some values into a Map u. I test the above class as follows.

```
Syst syst;
Map Lu;
syst.mysyst(u,Lu);
```

If I print out Lu.at(node).at(0), I get all elements 0, although I re-assigned 25 elements of Lu[node][0] with the value 1.0. Why the elements did not get changed. Initially, Map u was created outside Syst. So, syst should be able to access u and Lu, no?

I have spent some time to understand the problem. I need to pass u, and want to compute Lu as a function of u, although I have not used this in the simple example. I would appreciate if someone is able to help.

Comment: What is `u` in `syst.mysyst(u,Lu)`?

Comment: u is a Map, which is created and assigned. The creation of u is fully testd. (see the typedef of Map).

Comment: You'll have to give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct and Compilable Example](http://www.sscce.org/).